# FastCGI using apache - not a script or wrong permission?

Tags: apache, permissions, fastcgi

I compiled my fcgi for apache like this:

```
g++ fcgistart.c -lfcgi
```

I got a `a.out` and configure it for apache using

```
a2enmod fastcgi
```

Now i read the [manual](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html)

> Any program assigned to the handler fcgid-script is processed using the FastCGI protocol;

Does that mean the binary is a script? Wreid! Anyway I place the `a.out` to `/var/www/html`.

Because the handler (/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/fastcgi.conf) binds to `.fcgi` I copy `a.out` to `a.fcgi`. Now i browse to `http://localhost/a.fcgi` and a **403-forbidden** occourse.

```
xx@xx:/var/www/html$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Feb  6 13:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb  6 12:56 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  8696 Feb  6 13:44 a.fcgi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  8696 Feb  6 13:16 a.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11321 Feb  6 12:57 index.html
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

is wrong, I had to add the `ExecCGI` option:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options +ExecCGI
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```